# Lodash chain implementation

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I am mainly trying to avoid the nested `forEach` statements and am trying to move towards a lazy evaluation type solution.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2odrwat/)

```
var skus = [{
    "id": 25175837,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750485,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 0,
    "colorId": 19219,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/4/_7075044.jpg",
        "size": "1X",
    "color": "Navy",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175838,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750486,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075044,
    "colorId": 159942,
    "swatchImageUrl": "",
        "size": "2X",
    "color": "Navy",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175839,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750487,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075044,
    "colorId": 159942,
    "swatchImageUrl": "",
        "size": "3X",
    "color": "Navy",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175840,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750488,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075044,
    "colorId": 159942,
    "swatchImageUrl": "",
        "size": "4X",
    "color": "Navy",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175841,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750489,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075044,
    "colorId": 159942,
    "swatchImageUrl": "",
        "size": "5X",
    "color": "Navy",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175843,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750508,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075040,
    "colorId": 118311,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
        "size": "1X",
    "color": "Rl Black",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175844,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750509,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075040,
    "colorId": 118311,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
        "size": "2X",
    "color": "Rl Black",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175845,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750510,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
        "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075040,
    "colorId": 118311,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
        "size": "3X",
    "color": "Rl Black",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
        "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175846,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750511,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
    "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075040,
    "colorId": 118311,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
    "size": "4X",
    "color": "Rl Black",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
    "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
    "id": 25175847,
    "giftOptions": 1,
    "rmsSkuId": 53750512,
    "available": 1,
    "backOrder": "",
    "channelId": 1,
    "photoGroupId": 7075040,
    "colorId": 118311,
    "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
    "size": "5X",
    "color": "Rl Black",
    "width": null,
    "value": "",
    "price": "$50.00",
    "choiceGroup": "Tall",
    "isHolidayAvailable": true,
    "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}];
```

```js
_(skus)
    .groupBy(function (n) {
        return n.color;
    })
    .forEach(function (n, key) {
        var firstObj = n[0],
            correctColorId = firstObj.colorId;

        // is it possible to chain this forEach to the previous one? or some other
        // cleaner work around
        n.forEach(function (obj, index) {            
            if (obj.colorId !== correctColorId) {
                _.assign(obj, {colorId: correctColorId});
            }
        });
    });

console.log(skus);
```

Comment: Where do you want to apply lazy evaluation here?

Comment: instead of looping through the groups and looping through their contents, I should only need to loop through the specific keys of the groups thats matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Immutable vs. mutable

This is just my opinion, but I often prefer immutable methods over mutable methods. In this case, `skus` is mutating due to the use of `forEach`. However, if `skus` was required elsewhere in its original form, it would require several code changes in order to make it immutable.

For that reason, I often prefer `map` over `forEach` as it gives me the choice to mutate the original value or not. `map` would only require a variable change to make it mutable by assigning the value back to the original variable.

### Flat Solution

This problem, one can be solved without `forEach` and/or nested `forEach` methods. This solution also requires only 2 passes over the data.

1. Sort Items by the key field.
2. Loop through the items and compare them to the previous item.
3. Resolve any inconsistencies.

### The Code

For this demo, instead of mutating `skus`, the results are stored in a new variable called `test`. However, to mutate `skus`, one can just assign the value back to `skus`.

```
var test = _.chain(skus)
            .sortBy('color')
            .map(function(item, index, collection) {
                var lastIndex = index - 1;
                if (lastIndex > -1 
                    && item.color === collection[lastIndex].color
                    && item.colorId !== collection[lastIndex].colorId) {
                    item.colorId = collection[lastIndex].colorId;
                }
                return item;
            })
            .value();
```

### Demo

```js
var skus = [{
  "id": 25175837,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750485,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 0,
  "colorId": 19219,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/4/_7075044.jpg",
  "size": "1X",
  "color": "Navy",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175838,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750486,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075044,
  "colorId": 159942,
  "swatchImageUrl": "",
  "size": "2X",
  "color": "Navy",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175839,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750487,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075044,
  "colorId": 159942,
  "swatchImageUrl": "",
  "size": "3X",
  "color": "Navy",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175840,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750488,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075044,
  "colorId": 159942,
  "swatchImageUrl": "",
  "size": "4X",
  "color": "Navy",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175841,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750489,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075044,
  "colorId": 159942,
  "swatchImageUrl": "",
  "size": "5X",
  "color": "Navy",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175843,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750508,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075040,
  "colorId": 118311,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
  "size": "1X",
  "color": "Rl Black",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175844,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750509,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075040,
  "colorId": 118311,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
  "size": "2X",
  "color": "Rl Black",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175845,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750510,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075040,
  "colorId": 118311,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
  "size": "3X",
  "color": "Rl Black",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175846,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750511,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075040,
  "colorId": 118311,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
  "size": "4X",
  "color": "Rl Black",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}, {
  "id": 25175847,
  "giftOptions": 1,
  "rmsSkuId": 53750512,
  "available": 1,
  "backOrder": "",
  "channelId": 1,
  "photoGroupId": 7075040,
  "colorId": 118311,
  "swatchImageUrl": "SwatchSmall/0/_7075040.jpg",
  "size": "5X",
  "color": "Rl Black",
  "width": null,
  "value": "",
  "price": "$50.00",
  "choiceGroup": "Tall",
  "isHolidayAvailable": true,
  "isSameDayDeliveryAvailable": true
}];

var test = _.chain(skus)
  .sortBy('color')
  .map(function(item, index, collection) {
    var lastIndex = index - 1;
    if (lastIndex > -1 && item.color === collection[lastIndex].color && item.colorId !== collection[lastIndex].colorId) {
      item.colorId = collection[lastIndex].colorId;
    }
    return item;
  })
  .value();

console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```